# Converting a cell's formula to text using excel vba

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I am writing a macro in Excel2003 to find all cells with formulas in a workbook and outputting their address and formula in a couple of columns on a different sheet.

I know I can show the formula for an individual cell using

```
Public Function ShowFormula(cell As Range) As String

    ShowFormula = cell.Formula

End Function
```

which works just fine, but since I didn't want to have to find all the cells by hand, I wrote the following macro to find them all for me

```
Sub Macro2()


Dim i As Integer
Dim targetCells As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim referenceRange As Range
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet

Set referenceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("CA1")

With referenceRange
    For Each thisSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If thisSheet.Index >= referenceRange.Parent.Index Then
            Set targetCells = thisSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23)
            For Each cell In targetCells
                If cell.HasFormula Then
                    .Offset(i, 0).Value = thisSheet.Name
                    .Offset(i, 1).Value = cell.Address
                    .Offset(i, 2).Value = CStr(cell.Formula)
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

It finds all the cells just fine, but instead of displaying the formula as text, the list displays the formula results.

What am I missing to output the formulas as text instead of formulas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Offset(i, 2).Value = "'" & CStr(cell.Formula)
```

Also, this will make things a bit quicker. Instead of

```
For Each thisSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If thisSheet.Index >= referenceRange.Parent.Index Then
```

try

```
For j = referenceRange.Parent.Index to Sheets.Count
    Set thisSheet = Sheets(j)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip for speeding things up! Quick question on your answer. Whilst this works, it outputs `'=A1+B2+C3+...`. I am planning on plugging those formulas back into different cells later and this will require removing the "'". Is there a way to do this without forcing a text format? I really wonder why it works with the UDF and not within the macro...?

Comment: Removing the "'" is trivial `Right(s, Len(s) - 1)` but I take your point. You could try setting the format of the destination cell to Text before pasting the unmodified formula and see how that goes.

Comment: Formatting to text did that trick. So simple, yet it didn't occur to me :( Many thanks!